# jQuery - Save / Update Credit Cards using Stripe Element and Local Storage

Tags: jquery, stripe-payments

In a test environment, I am trying to hook the `Stripe Elements` Credit Card validator into code that is set up to save the validated form information as well as update stored information. The code is to simulate a `checkout UX` where users can enter new credit card information (using the Stripe Elements form) and save their validated information using `local storage`.

In addition to being able to save their new cards, they can update cards that were already saved / appear on load.

The problem I have is that I am unsure how to define the `var valid = ();` that would loop the Stripe Elements form with the update / save code as well as run two instances of the Stripe validator (one for new cards, and another for updating saved cards).

Here is the codepen: https://codepen.io/moofawsaw/pen/jOOwbwG

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var stripe = Stripe("pk_test_6pRNASCoBOKtIshFeQd4XMUh");
  var elements = stripe.elements();

  var style = {
    base: {
      iconColor: "#666EE8",
      color: "#31325F",
      lineHeight: "40px",
      fontWeight: 600,
      fontSize: "16px",

      "::placeholder": {
        color: "#CFD7E0",
        fontWeight: 400
      }
    }
  };

  var cardNumberElement = elements.create("cardNumber", {
    style: style
  });
  cardNumberElement.mount("#cc-number");

  var cardExpiryElement = elements.create("cardExpiry", {
    style: style
  });
  cardExpiryElement.mount("#cc-exp");

  var cardCvcElement = elements.create("cardCvc", {
    style: style
  });
  cardCvcElement.mount("#cc-cvc");

  function setOutcome(result) {
    var successElement = document.querySelector(".success");
    var errorElement = document.querySelector(".error");
    successElement.classList.remove("visible");
    errorElement.classList.remove("visible");

    if (result.token) {
      // In this example, we're simply displaying the token
      successElement.querySelector(".token").textContent = result.token.id;
      successElement.classList.add("visible");

      // In a real integration, you'd submit the form with the token to your backend server
      //var form = document.querySelector('form');
      //form.querySelector('input[name="token"]').setAttribute('value', result.token.id);
      //form.submit();
    } else if (result.error) {
      errorElement.textContent = result.error.message;
      errorElement.classList.add("visible");
    }
  }

  var cardBrandToPfClass = {
    visa: "pf-visa",
    mastercard: "pf-mastercard",
    amex: "pf-american-express",
    discover: "pf-discover",
    diners: "pf-diners",
    jcb: "pf-jcb",
    unknown: "pf-credit-card"
  };

  function setBrandIcon(brand) {
    var brandIconElement = document.getElementById("brand-icon");
    var pfClass = "pf-credit-card";
    if (brand in cardBrandToPfClass) {
      pfClass = cardBrandToPfClass[brand];
    }
    for (var i = brandIconElement.classList.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
      brandIconElement.classList.remove(brandIconElement.classList[i]);
    }
    brandIconElement.classList.add("pf");
    brandIconElement.classList.add(pfClass);
  }

  cardNumberElement.on("change", function(event) {
    // Switch brand logo
    if (event.brand) {
      setBrandIcon(event.brand);
    }

    setOutcome(event);
  });

  document.querySelector(".payment").addEventListener("submit", function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var options = {};
    stripe.createToken(cardNumberElement, options).then(setOutcome);
  });

  $(function() {
    var $selectedItem;

    window.localStorage.clear();
    if (!localStorage.getItem("_storage")) {
      localStorage.setItem("_storage", "");
    }
    //create localStorage item
    if (localStorage.getItem("_storage")) {
      $("#content").html(localStorage.getItem("_storage"));
    }
    //set data to localStorage function
    function saveData() {
      localStorage.setItem("_storage", $("#content").html());
    }

    $(".payment").on("click", ".btn--save", function() {

      if (valid) {
        var id = $("#cc-cvc").val();
        var createnumb = $("#cc-number").val();
        var exp = $("#cc-exp").val();
        var item = "";
        if (id[0]) {
          for (var i = 0; i < id.length; i++) {
            item += "<div>" + id[i] + "</div>";
          }
        } else {
          item = "<div>Click update to add a card</div>";
        }
        $("#content").append(
          '<div class="checkout__card">' +
          '<div class="card__numb">' +
          createnumb +
          "</div>" +
          "<div class='card__cvc'>" +
          id +
          "</div>" +
          "<div class='card__exp'>" +
          exp +
          "</div>" +
          '<button class="card__remove">Delete</button>' +
          '<button class="card__update">Update</button>' +
          "</div>"
        );
        $("#cc-number").val("");
        $("#cc-exp").val("");
        $("#cc-cvc").val("");
        /*  $(".payment").toggle();*/
        saveData();
      }
    });
    //Close out of creating a new item
    /*  $(".close").click(function() {
    $("#cc-number").val("");
    $("#cc-cvc").val("");
    $(".create").toggle();
  });*/
    //Get inputs and open edit window to update the items:
    $("#content").on("click", ".card__update", function() {
      $selectedItem = $(this).closest(".checkout__card");
      $(".updatenumb").val(
        $(this)
        .closest(".checkout__card")
        .find(".card__numb")
        .text()
      );
      $(".updateexp").val(
        $(this)
        .closest(".checkout__card")
        .find(".card__exp")
        .text()
      );
      $(".updatecvc").val(
        $(this)
        .closest(".checkout__card")
        .find(".card__cvc")
        .text()
      );
      $(".card__modal").toggle();
    });
    //Save changes and update the items (error:changes all items when clicked):
    $(".card__modal").on("click", ".card__save", function() {

      if (valid) {
        var id = $(".updatecvc").val();
        var numb = $(".updatenumb").val();
        var exp = $(".updateexp").val();
        var item = "";
        if (id[0]) {
          for (var i = 0; i < id.length; i++) {
            item += "<div>" + id[i] + "</div>";
          }
        } else {
          item = "<p>Click edit to add a card</p>";
        }

        $selectedItem.html(
          '<div class="card__numb">' +
          numb +
          "</div>" +
          "<div class='card__cvc'>" +
          id +
          "</div>" +
          "<div class='card__exp'>" +
          exp +
          "</div>" +
          '<button class="card__remove">Deleted(saved)</button>' +
          '<button class="card__update">Updated(saved)</button>'
        );
        $(".updatenumb").val("");
        $(".updateexp").val("");
        $(".updatecvc").val("");
        $(".card__modal").toggle();
        saveData();
      } else {}
    });
    //Discard any of these changes:
    $(".card__discard").click(function() {
      $(".updatenumb").val("");
      $(".updateexp").val("");
      $(".updatecvc").val("");
      $(".card__modal").toggle();
    });
    //Delete an item:
    $("#content").on("click", ".card__remove", function() {
      $(this)
        .closest(".checkout__card")
        .remove();
      saveData();
    });
  });
});
```

```css
#content {
  display: flex;
  background-color: #f5f5f5;
  border: 1px solid #c2c2c2;
}

.checkout__card {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

.card__numb,
.card__cvc,
.card__exp {
  padding: 3px;
  margin: 3px;
  border: 1px solid;
}

payment__card,
.card__modal {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 10;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  width: 300px;
  height: 200px;
  overflow: hidden;
  border: 2px solid;
}

input {
  border: 2px solid;
}

.field {
  background: transparent;
  font-weight: 400;
  border: 0;
  color: #31325f;
  outline: none;
  flex: 1;
  padding-right: 10px;
  padding-left: 10px;
  cursor: text;
}

.field::-webkit-input-placeholder {
  color: #cfd7e0;
}

.field::-moz-placeholder {
  color: #cfd7e0;
}

.outcome {
  float: left;
  width: 100%;
  padding-top: 8px;
  min-height: 24px;
  text-align: center;
}

.success,
.error {
  display: none;
  font-size: 13px;
}

.success.visible,
.error.visible {
  display: inline;
}

.error {
  color: #e4584c;
}

.success {
  color: #666ee8;
}

.success .token {
  font-weight: 500;
  font-size: 13px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://js.stripe.com/v3/"></script>
<form class="payment" action="//httpbin.org/post" method="POST">
  <input type="hidden" name="token" />
  <div class="">
    <label>
        <span>Card number</span>
        <div id="cc-number" class="field"></div>
      </label>
    <label>
        <span>Expiry date</span>
        <div id="cc-exp" class="field"></div>
      </label>
    <label>
        <span>CVC</span>
        <div id="cc-cvc" class="field"></div>
      </label>
  </div>
  <button type="submit" class="btn--payment">Confirm</button>
  <button type="button" class="btn--save">Save</button>
  <div class="outcome">
    <div class="error"></div>
    <div class="success">
      Success! Your Stripe token is <span class="token"></span>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
<div id="container">
  <div id="content">
    <div class="checkout__card">
      <div class="card__numb">4353 2455 2346 8236</div>
      <p class="card__cvc">101</p>
      <p class="card__exp">01/24</p>
      <button class="card__remove">Delete</button>
      <button class="card__update">Update</button>
    </div>
  </div>
  <!-- <button class="btn--addcard">Add Card</button>-->
</div>

<div class="card__modal">
  <div class="card__board">
    <form class="payment" action="//httpbin.org/post" method="POST">
      <input type="hidden" name="token" />
      <div class="">
        <label>
        <span>Card number</span>
        <div class="field updatenumb"></div>
      </label>
        <label>
        <span>Expiry date</span>
        <div class="field updateexp"></div>
      </label>
        <label>
        <span>CVC</span>
        <div class="field updatecvc"></div>
      </label>
      </div>
      <button type="submit" class="btn--payment">Confirm</button>
      <button type="button" class="btn--save">Save</button>
      <div class="outcome">
        <div class="error"></div>
        <div class="success">
          Success! Your Stripe token is <span class="token"></span>
        </div>
      </div>
    </form>
    <button class="card__save">Save</button>
    <button class="card__discard">Discard</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 var valid = $(".card__board").paymentForm("valid");
```

You can't get the card valid state from the above code since there is no method called paymentForm in div element.

Instead, you can call the `stripe.createToken(cardNumberElement)` method on click of `.btn--save` button and get the card validity then proceed the save or update operation.

```
 $(".payment").on("click", ".btn--save", function() {
    stripe.createToken(cardNumberElement).then(function(result){
        if(result.token){
         // do your stuff
        }else{
       // show the error
       }
    });
 });
```

or else, on specific to your code you can have a global variable to maintain the card validity state, update the variable value on `.payment form submit` and check that variable on save or update button click.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  var stripe = Stripe("pk_test_6pRNASCoBOKtIshFeQd4XMUh");
  var elements = stripe.elements();
  var isValidCard =false;
 var style = {
    base: {
      iconColor: "#666EE8",
      color: "#31325F",
      lineHeight: "40px",
      fontWeight: 600,
      fontSize: "16px",

      "::placeholder": {
        color: "#CFD7E0",
        fontWeight: 400
      }
    }
  };

  var cardNumberElement = elements.create("cardNumber", {
    style: style
  });
  cardNumberElement.mount("#cc-number");

  var cardExpiryElement = elements.create("cardExpiry", {
    style: style
  });
  cardExpiryElement.mount("#cc-exp");

  var cardCvcElement = elements.create("cardCvc", {
    style: style
  });
  cardCvcElement.mount("#cc-cvc");

  function setOutcome(result) {
    var successElement = document.querySelector(".success");
    var errorElement = document.querySelector(".error");
    successElement.classList.remove("visible");
    errorElement.classList.remove("visible");

    if (result.token) {
      // In this example, we're simply displaying the token
      successElement.querySelector(".token").textContent = result.token.id;
      successElement.classList.add("visible");
      isValidCard = true;
      // In a real integration, you'd submit the form with the token to your backend server
      //var form = document.querySelector('form');
      //form.querySelector('input[name="token"]').setAttribute('value', result.token.id);
      //form.submit();
    } else if (result.error) {
      errorElement.textContent = result.error.message;
      errorElement.classList.add("visible");
      isValidCard=false;
    }
  }
   document.querySelector(".payment").addEventListener("submit", function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var options = {};
    stripe.createToken(cardNumberElement, options).then(setOutcome);
  });

    $(".payment").on("click", ".btn--save", function() {
     // var valid = $(".card__board").paymentForm("valid");
      if(isValidCard){
      }
    });

});
```

Comment: Hi Rajesh, if you are able to provide a working snippet I will award the bounty

Comment: @KyleUnderhill please find my [example](https://codepen.io/rajeshyazh/pen/ExxEyjY) which contains card validation on form submit. you can't get the sensitive values like the card number and cvv from stripe elements. you can perform the payment operations by using that card token.